# Show that $a^2 = b$ in a field $\mathbb{F} = \{0,1,a,b\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

I need some help proving the following:

> Let $\mathbb{F} = \{0, 1, a, b\}$ be a field with four elements. Prove that $a^2 = b$.
>   You can use $a \cdot 0 = 0$ without proving it.

Attempted solution:

$$
a^2 = b \\
aa = b \\
aa + 0 = b + 0
$$
We know $a \cdot 0 = 0$ so we can substitute for zero
$$
 aa + a \cdot 0 = b
$$
Using the additive inverse of $aa$ we get:
$$
 (aa) + (-aa) + a \cdot 0 = b + (-aa) \\
 a \cdot 0 = b + (-aa)
$$
I’m still not getting the concept of how to prove things, maybe a little insight into what are possible steps to approach problems like these.

Thats as far as I got, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can the multiplicative group of F in this case be regarded as the Klein four group? Thanks in any case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $0$ and $1$ are distinguished elements, so none of the others should be equal to them.
Now, $b \cdot a$ cannot be equal to $a$ or $b$ becaus then $b$ or $a$ would be $1$, respectively, but that cannot happen as they are distinct elements. Similarly, $b \cdot a$ cannot be $0$. Hence, $b \cdot a = 1$.

Use this type of reasoning to think what $a^2$ *cannot* be, and you'll find the anwser: what is $a$ if $a^2 = 0$?

Comment: But how did you arrive at b⋅a = 1, i didnt understand that?

Comment: Just because there are 4 options (as there are four elements). And I showed that $b \cdot a$ cannot be the other three, hence it *must* be the fourth.this is an easiest way to argue, i.e prove what $a^2$ can't be. i had the very same question on a problem set in my first year algebra course and that is how i solved it.

Comment: Right i see. So essentially there are 4 possibilities to a^2 = 0. The first is a^2 = 0 cannot be true since that makes a = 0. The second is that a^2 = 1, which also cannot be true since that means a = 1. The third is a^2 = a which also is not true since that makes a = 1. The fourth then must be true which is a^2 = b. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: You can also check that $b = a^{-1} = a^2 = a+1 $

Comment: Great, i think im getting this now. Suppose that there were more than 4 elements, would there be a better way than to check each possibility?

Comment: If there were more than 4 elements, the operations need not be defined uniquely. Here there's really not much choice

Comment: Ahh i see, cool. Mann i got a quiz on wednesday so im really pushing to get these down. Thanks again!

Comment: I think $a^{2}=1$ does not imply a=1, for @1337holiday, rather, this will on;y imply that a is idempotent; and to get the right answer, note that ab=1, and hence, in this case, aa=ab, i.e. a=b, which is impossible since a is different from b. Thanks in any case.

Comment: Yes, it is in fact the case that $a^2 = 1$ implies $a=1$. Check Jay's answer below.

Answer (score 8):

Consider that the map $x \mapsto ax$ must be bijective (because the field is finite -- should be easy to show). We know,
$$a \cdot 0 = 0$$
$$a \cdot 1 = a$$
This means $a\cdot a = b$ or $a \cdot a = 1.$ But in the latter case we get $a \cdot b = b,$ which implies $a = 1,$ which is not true (by uniqueness of 1).