# How can I find the sum and multiplication table of a $F_4$ field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

From the field $\{0,1,A,B\}$ I know that, by exhaustion, $A\cdot B=1$ but how do I get $A \cdot A $ and $B\cdot B$?
How can I get the sum table?
We haven't been thought almost anything about fields in class yet so I am stuck even with the other answers on the internet.
I need a full explanation. I don't know what cyclic means or anything pretty much about fields.

Comment: The multiplicative group of a finite field is cyclic

Comment: There is a field of order 4 by using the irreducible quadratic $x^2+x+1$ [over integers mod 2]. Look up "finite fields" somewhere...

Comment: This has been handled many times. [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/42143/11619) is perhaps the highest voted version. You may also find [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/19621/11619) helpful, and more recently we had [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1936077/11619) thread. That last item may be close to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $B=A+1$. Hence if you already know $AB=1$, we conclude $AA=A(B-1)=AB-A=1-A=1+A=B$ and $BB=(A+1)B=AB+B=1+B=2+A=A$.

Comment: You are missing at least the derivations of $B=A+1$ and $1+1=0$ (compare to the most recent [reincarnation of this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1936077/11619). Of course, you are free to make assumptions about what the OP knows already.

Comment: OP knows nothing about this. How do you get the derivation of $B = A + 1$? Also, it seems that $A\cdot A$ can't be $A$. Can you show this with multiplication only and not knowing $A+A$, $A+B$ or $B+B$